# How to continue a mergeMap when one fails in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, mergemap

I can't seem to figure out how to continue with a `mergeMap` in Angular when one fails.

I'm stringing together two `mergeMap` calls on an observable inside `pipe`. Both finish all their calls, but one of the second merge map calls return an error, so none of the second merge calls get mapped.

```js
Observable.pipe(
   mergeMap(
     result => {
       return stuff
       });
     }
   ), mergeMap(result => {
     return stuff //one of the calls here will error, but the rest work
   }),
   catchError(error => {
     return of(undefined)
   })
 ).subscribe({
   next: (result) => {
     //this will be undefined if one of the above calls failed, works otherwise
     if(result != undefined)
   { 
   //stuff
   }
```

I'm still very new to this so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to chain `catchError()` with the nested Observable before the error is propagated to the main chain.

```
source$.pipe(
  mergeMap(result => stuff.pipe(
    catchError(error => {
      return of(undefined);
    }),
  )),
  mergeMap(result => stuff.pipe(
    catchError(error => {
      return of(undefined);
    })
  )),
);
```

Of course the second `mergeMap` needs to be able to handle `undefined` returned by the first `mergeMap`.